# How to pull a unknown URL out of a String

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a Node/Express app and I have a text string in a JSON object that I need to pull a URL out of. The URL is different every time, and the string itself has two very similar URL's, and I only want to pull out one.

The only thing I do know is that in the string, the url will always be preceded with the same text.

String:

```
The following new or updated things match your search criteria.

Link I Need
<http://randomurl.com/Junk/Yay/ThisView.aspx?r=164241242186&s=J
WD&t=JWD> 

Link I don't Need
<http://randomurl.com/Junk/Yay/ThisView.aspx?r=164241242186&s=J
WD&t=JWD&m=true> 

Search was last updated on April 12th, 2013 @ 14:43 

If you wish to unsubscribe from this update...
```

Out of this string all  I need to pull out is the URL under `Link I Need`, `http://randomurl.com/Junk/Yay/ThisView.aspx?r=164241242186&s=J
    WD&t=JWD` and nothing else. I'm not quite sure how to go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What defines the you need? Is it the first one that appears? The one without `m=true`?

Comment: Regular expressions would be the sensible choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var s = "The following new or updated ...";
var regex = /Link I Need\s*<([^>]*)>/;
var match = s.match(regex);
var theUrl = match && match[1];
```

This assumes that the URL is not split across newlines. If it is, then after you find the match, you need to to

```
theUrl = theUrl.replace(/\s+/, '')
```